# Are FCM messages on android more reliable than they were?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

A couple of years ago to ensure reliably receiving push notifications from Firebase/GCM to Android app you needed to have a heartbeat to keep the connection alive. Is this still necessary or has the issue been fixed in a satisfactory way?

Comment: Well I do not know this issue. But our application is fairly new and does not need a heartbeat. I'd say it's fixed.

Comment: The heartbeat problem i'm referring to is mentioned here...https://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/

Comment: FCM and GCM aren't even the same thing, you shouldn't draw conclusions for FCM based on what was said for GCM *years* ago

Comment: @MarkSheekey I experienced unreliability: sometimes I can't reach the app anymore after a few hours. None of my notifications would be received. After restarting the app manually, I suddenly receive all the old ones. No idea why. Good luck! :)

Comment: @Mr.B.: If you are sending data messages (not notifications), they must be sent with high priority to wake a sleeping device.  Otherwise they are queued and sent when some other event causes the device to exit sleep mode.

Comment: @BobSnyder Thank you, I'll give it a try!

Comment: @MarkSheekey I'm the author of the blog post you mentioned. FCM has inherited GCM's architecture years ago which means it also inherited its lack of reliability. That was years ago, but it seems reliability hasn't improved much ever since. You'll find that notifications sent through FCM constantly get throttled and will still fail to register some devices due to the `SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error. To be able to deliver notifications reliably, I founded Pushy (https://pushy.me/) which utilizes an underlying fine-tuned MQTT connection to deliver your notifications without relying on GCM/FCM.

Answer (score 0):

Its still on testing phase for now.If you ask about reliability of receiving notification so far its  not  fully reliable.Sometimes messages are received within a few seconds, sometimes after a few minutes (could even be over 10 and even 20 minutes!).

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/83

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/194